# Add bold font to the itemize environment

Tags: fonts, lists, itemize

I am trying to list some items in my document so that I can add  bold option to the words in the item such as below:

- **src** contains the activities  as well as the java code.
- **gen** contains the activities  as well as the java code.
- **assets** contains the activities  as well as the java code.
- **bin** contains the activities  as well as the java code.

But with this code the items are being created without the bold font option. How can I achieve that with `itemize` or other enviremnt?

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item  src contains the activities  as well as the java code.
  \item gen
  \item assets
  \item bin
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post working examples, not fragments of code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\textbf` makes the argument bold. An alternative is environment `description`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{src} contains the activities  as well as the Java code.
  \item \textbf{gen}
  \item \textbf{assets}
  \item \textbf{bin}
\end{itemize}

\hrule

\begin{description}
  \item[src] contains the activities  as well as the Java code.
  \item[gen]
  \item[assets]
  \item[bin]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to define a new environment, so you can change its realization by just modifying the relevant definitions; `enumitem` is very handy for this when dealing with lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{descitemize} % a mixture of description and itemize
  {\begin{description}[leftmargin=*,before=\let\makelabel\descitemlabel]}
  {\end{description}}

\newcommand{\descitemlabel}[1]{%
  \textbullet\ \textbf{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{descitemize}
  \item[src] contains the activities  as well as the Java code.
  \item[gen]
  \item[assets]
  \item[bin]
\end{descitemize}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{description}
  \item[src] contains the activities  as well as the Java code.
  \item[gen]
  \item[assets]
  \item[bin]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

The `description` environment is just for comparison.

[image]

If you want the marker to agree with the general `itemize` markers when nesting `descitemize` environments, some more works has to be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{descitemize} % a mixture of description and itemize
  {\begin{description}[leftmargin=*,before=\let\makelabel\descitemlabel\advanceitemdepth]}
  {\end{description}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\advanceitemdepth}{%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth >\thr@@
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\descitemlabel}[1]{%
  \csname\@itemitem\endcsname\ \textbf{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{descitemize}
  \item[src] contains the activities  as well as the Java code.
  \item[gen]
  \item[assets]
  \item[bin] is divided into two
    \begin{descitemize}
    \item[zero] for $0$
    \item[one] for $1$
  \end{descitemize}
\end{descitemize}
\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One option is to manually make the text you want bold.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item  \textbf{src} contains the activities  as well as the java code.
  \item \textbf{gen} 
  \item \textbf{assets}
   \item \textbf{bin}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Furthermore, another option which gives you a new environment for bold prefixes (`bolditemize`), while keeping the bulleted list. Visually, it will look exactly the same as the method above.

```
\newenvironment{bolditemize}{\begin{itemize} }{\end{itemize}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\bolditemize\expandafter{%
 \bolditemize \let\olditem\item
  \def\item[##1]{\olditem \textbf{##1}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{bolditemize}
     \item[src]  contains the activities  as well as the java code.
     \item[gen] 
     \item[assests] 
     \item[bin] 
 \end{bolditemize}
 \end{document}
```